# Calling original function from Sinon.js Stub

Tags: sinon

I'm trying to intercept a call with Sinon.js so I can do some logging and then execute the original call.  I don't see a way to do this with sinon.spy(), but I think I can do it with sinon.stub().

I provided a custom function:

```
sinon.stub(servicecore.ServiceWrapper.prototype, '_invoke', function(method, name, body, headers, callback) {
    console.log('---- ServiceWrapper._invoke called! ----');

// How do I call the original function?

});
```

The problem I have is executing the original function, so my application behaves the same.  Any idea?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use a closure.  For example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function () {
        console.log('foo');
    }
};

var stub = (function () {
    var originalFoo = obj.foo;
    return sinon.stub(obj, 'foo', function () {
        console.log('stub');
        originalFoo();
    });
}());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BByHH/)

Comment: Thanks!  Found this comment in [Sinonjs github](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/pull/278#issuecomment-34047017) which explained it also.

Comment: thanks. I think you might need to do `var originalFoo = obj.foo.bind(obj)`

Answer (score 15):

Sinon stores a reference to the original function in the [`wrappedMethod` property of the stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) (docs were just recently added in 2020). This can be called in the fake method.

```js
sinon.stub(Array.prototype, 'sort').callsFake(
  // Don't use arrow function => syntax if you need to use 'this' below!
  function () {
    console.log(`sorting array ${this}`);
    return Array.prototype.sort.wrappedMethod.apply(this, arguments);
  }
);

const array = ['C', 'A', 'B'].sort();
console.log(`sorted array is ${array}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/7.3.2/sinon.min.js"></script>
```

And so the OP's code would be:

```js
sinon.stub(servicecore.ServiceWrapper.prototype, '_invoke').callsFake(function(method, name, body, headers, callback) {
    console.log('---- ServiceWrapper._invoke called! ----');
    return servicecore.ServiceWrapper.prototype._invoke.wrappedMethod.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: Added an edit to call out that if you need to use `this` with the `wrappedMethod.apply()` call, you can't use arrow function syntax `()=>{}`. That's probably the syntax most people use for sinon stubs most of the time, but arrow functions get their `this` value from their closure, which would be the wrong value here.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the original method stored the in stub using the `wrappedMethod` property.

It is useful to reference the stub using a closure, avoid a messy `this` context, and allowing you to use a lambda function for the `fake callback`.

```js
const stub = sinon.stub(patchSync, 'patchRemote').callsFake((...args) => {
  console.log('before call')
  const result =  stub.wrappedMethod(...args)
  console.log('after call')
  return result
})
```