# How do I override config values at runtime with node-config?

Tags: node.js, testing, configuration, hapi.js, node-config

I'd like to override some values at test-time, specifically setting my retries for an http service to 1 (immediate failure, no retries). Our project uses `node-config`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Command-Line-Overrides) I can override with `NODE_CONFIG` env variable:

```
node myapp.js --NODE_CONFIG='{"Customer":{"dbConfig":{"host":"customerdb.prod"}}}'
```

Well I would prefer to do this in my test, but not for all tests. The [code](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/blob/083a783daa5e2426d679890ae7e3fb3149100d13/lib/config.js#L186) says that you can allow config mutations by setting `ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS`.

```
process.env.ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS = "true";
const importFresh = require('import-fresh');
importFresh("config");

process.env.NODE_CONFIG = JSON.stringify({httpServices:{integration:{enrich: {retryInterval: 1, retries: 1}}}});
expect(process.env.NODE_CONFIG, 'NODE_CONFIG not set').to.exist();
expect(process.env.NODE_CONFIG, 'NODE_CONFIG not set').to.match(/retryInterval/);
expect(process.env.ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS, 'ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS not set').to.equal("true");

const testConfig = require("config");
console.dir(testConfig.get("httpServices.integration.enrich"));
expect(testConfig.get("httpServices.integration.enrich.retryInterval"), 'config value not set to 1').to.equal(1);
```

Result:

```
{ url: 'https://internal-**********',
  retryInterval: 5000,
  retries: 5 }
 `Error: config value not set to 1: Expected 5000 to equal specified value: 1`
```

How do I get this override to work?

(expect is from Hapi.js Code library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of `node-config`. Your bug is that you used `require` the second time when you should have used `importFresh` again.

Your first use of "importFresh()" does nothing different than `require()` would, because it is the first use of `require()`.

After setting some variables, you call `require()`, which will return the copy of `config` already generated and cached, ignoring the effects of the environment variables set.

You only needed to use `importFresh()` once, where you currently  use `require()`. This will cause a "fresh" copy of the config object to be returned, as you expected.

Answer (score 3):

Simply changing `config`'s property worked for me.
For example:

```
const config = require( 'config' ); 

config.httpServices.integration.enrich.retryInterval = 1;

// Do your tests...
```

UPD: Make sure that overrides are done before anyone calls the first `config.get()`, because the `config` object is made immutable as soon as any client uses the values via `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Joining late, but other answers did not fit with the testing standard in my project, so here is what I came up with

## TL;DR

Use mocks..

## Detailed Answer

node-config uses a function `get` to get the configuration values.
By mocking the function `get` you can easily modify any configuration you see fit..

My personal favorite library is sinon

Here is an implementation of a mock with sinon

```
const config = require('config');
const sinon = require('sinon');
class MockConfig {
    constructor () {
       this.params = {};
       this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    }
    withConfValue (confKey, confValue) {
        this.params.confValues[confKey] = confValue;
        return this;
    }
    reset () {
        this.params.confValues: {};
        return this;
    }
    restore() {
       this.sandbox.restore();
    }
    apply () {
        this.restore(); // avoid duplicate wrapping
        this.sandbox.stub(config, 'get').callsFake((configKey) => {
            if (this.params.confValues.hasOwnProperty(configKey)) {
                return this.params.confValues[configKey];
            }
            // not ideal.. however `wrappedMethod` approach did not work for me
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017971/1068746
            return configKey
               .split('.')
               .reduce((result, item) => result[item], config)
            
        });
    }
}

const instance = new MockConfig();
MockConfig.instance = () => instance;

module.exports = MockConfig;
```

Usage would be

```
const mockConfig = require('./mock_config').instance();

...
beforeEach(function () {
    mockConfig.reset().apply();
})

afterEach(function () {
     mockConfig.reset().clear();
})


it('should do something') {
    mockConfig.withConfValue('some_topic.some_field.property', someValue);
    ... rest of the test ... 
}
```

## Assumptions

The only assumption this approach makes is that you adhere to node-config way of reading the configuration (using the `get` function) and not bypass it by accessing fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a development.json, production.json et test.json in your config folder node-config will use it your app configuration. 
you just net to set your NODE_ENV to use the specific file.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Not really. I want to be able to change my config in a specific test, not for all tests. As I mentioned: "Well I would prefer to do this in my test, but not for all tests."

Comment: @jcollum Ok i understand. Did you try to export config like `export NODE_CONFIG='{"Customer":{"dbConfig":{"host":"customerdb.prod"}}}'`

Comment: Did you read my source code? It seems to answer your question.

Comment: I meant exporting it on your .bashrc / .bash_profile not by add --NODE_CONFIG

Comment: But that would mean that I'm setting it for all tests. Or I have to have a separate NPM test call per config. This isn't optimal.