# Passing context to Sinon stub's fake function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using the [mochawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome) test reporter for my mocha tests. I'd like it to record my logging as well, and attach it to whatever test was running when the log was written. This can be achieved with `addContext()`. However, I *also* want the logs to output to the console, so I can monitor them as the test is running, rather than wait til it all finishes and the report is generated.

I've got 98% of a solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714085/calling-original-function-from-sinon-js-stub), but am struggling based on the fact that mochawesome's `addContext()` requires you to pass it a test object. Here's what I've got:

```js
beforeEach(`Spy on logger`, function() {
  const origLogInfo = logger.info.bind(logger),
    origLogError = logger.error.bind(logger),
    testContext = this

  sinon.stub(logger, 'info').callsFake(function(message) {
    addContext(testContext, `INFO: ${message}`)
    origLogInfo.call(testContext, message)
  })

  sinon.stub(logger, 'error').callsFake(function(message) {
    addContext(testContext, `ERROR: ${message}`)
    origLogError.call(testContext, message)
  })
})

afterEach(`Remove stubs`, function() {
  logger.info.restore()
  logger.error.restore()
})

it('counts approved hours', async function() {
      logger.info(`Approving timesheets...`)
        ...
```

So before each `it()`, I get a reference to the original `logger.info()` and `logger.error()` functions, then I stub them. The stub calls a function which calls mochawesome's `addContext()` function, passing it a reference to the `beforeEach()` and whatever string I've sent to `logger.info()`. Then the original is called.

My problem is that every time `addContext()` is called, it attaches the logs to the `beforeEach()` hook. I can see why it's happening, too. Stepping through the code reveals that when `beforeEach()` is executing, `this` has two properties: `currentTest`, and `test`. The former refers to the `it()` which is about to be called, and the latter is the `beforeEach()` hook itself. This is great! If it stayed like this, `addContext()` would pick up `currentTest` and attach the logs to it ([link to source](https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome/blob/798911ff7d57303ef20181b7d6ba9e7f69227839/src/addContext.js#L89)).

By the time the argument to `callsFake()` is called, however, that same object has lost its `currentTest` property, so `addContext()` instead attaches the logs to the `beforeEach()` hook itself. Resulting in a test report with all the logs attached to the `beforeEach` hook instead of the relevant tests.

Is there any way I can write this so the `callsFake()` argument has a reference to the test that `logger.info` was called from? The following works, but requires extra code inside each `it()`:

```js
boundLoggerInfo = logger.info.bind(this);
boundLoggerInfo(`Approving timesheets...`)
```

Cheers! Hopefully I've provided enough info without being *too* verbose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I managed to work around the issue and achieve what I was after, after a good night's sleep:

```js
testContext = {
  currentTest: this.currentTest
}
```

Now a reference to currentTest is maintained even after `beforeEach()` loses it (still not sure why that happens).